# Find the nearest value in multiplication table

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers

Let's say I have multiplication table 20 `a = 20`

A point on grid let say say 517 `b = 517`

Now I need a formula to find nearest number on both sides of this point on multiplication table. The answer will be 500 and 520. What could be the formula to get these both numbers using a and b

Or in other words closest multiples of 20 on either side of 517?

Comment: I don't understand the tagging of the question.  To be honest, I don't understand the question at all.

Comment: I have a grid that is 20 times a number. pointer is at 517 px and I need to know nearest point on grid formula in the multiplication table 20. The answer would be 500 and 520. Does it make sense?

Comment: So in your example, you're looking for the closest multiples of $20$ on either side of $517$? And you want a general formula for the closest multiples of $a$ on either side of $b$?

Comment: The reason we don't have a word limit in a question is so that the O.P can easily explain and clarify his question . Take your time to properly write everything in a way that anyone can understand your problem without any prior knowledge .

Comment: @Dave is right I am looking for  closest multiples of 20 on either side of 517?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, the reason we get the answer to be $500$ and $520$ is because $$\lfloor517\div20\rfloor=25\quad\text{and}\quad20\times25=500\quad\text{and}\quad20\times26=520.$$

As such, in general, we have the two answers as needed as $$a\left\lfloor\frac{b}{a}\right\rfloor\quad\text{and}\quad a\left(\left\lfloor\frac{b}{a}\right\rfloor+1\right).$$

Comment: Thank you that seems to have solved my problem

Answer (score 5):

I believe you are looking for the two numbers
$$a\left\lfloor\frac{b}{a}\right\rfloor,\quad a\left\lceil\frac{b}{a}\right\rceil$$
using the floor and ceiling functions respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer but unfortunately I wasn't able to find a ceiling function in JS that accepts two arguments.

Comment: I didn't write it with two arguments. The *single* argument is the fraction $b/a$.